# Can't connect tableau to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api

I'm struggling with this problem for many days
In my cmd showed...

```
2020-06-25T16:54:34.541+0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-06-25T16:54:34.541+0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-06-25T16:54:34.541+0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.

2020-06-29T08:50:44.280+0700 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 127.0.0.1
2020-06-29T08:50:44.280+0700 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Here's my Error Message from Tableau

```
An error occurred while communicating with MongoDB BI Connector
Unable to connect to the server. Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.
Error Code: 37CE01A3
[MySQL][ODBC 1.0(w) Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060
Unable to connect to the MongoDB BI Connector server "127.0.0.1". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.
```

Answer (score 0):

That log appears to come from a mongod node.

In order to connect with Tableau, you will need to use the connector for BI.

See https://www.mongodb.com/tableau